# Error : Undefined index: image for ($_FILES['image']['name'])

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple registration form, in which I accept inputs from the user that includes an image, and insert the values in a table : temporary_employees table . In my code, I check whether the email id and the user id entered by the user already exists and if they dont , i go ahead and perform the insert after moving the image  to a folder named 'images' . While running the code , I am getting an error **Undefined index: image**, on the line where I have the following piece of code :

```
$target_file = $target_path . basename ($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

**The most interesting thing is the same line of code has worked perfectly well in another php file . I had given the same name for the input in the html form .** . How is it possible ? Any help will be appreciated .

Here is my code :

```
//start the session before anything is echoed to the browser
if (session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login form
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Registration Form</h3>
<form action ="" method="POST">
<table align="center" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength='100' name="empname" id="empname" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email Id</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength='100' name="emailid" id="emailid" required>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User Id</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength='100' name="userid" id="userid" required ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" maxlength='100' name="pwd" id="pwd" required ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date of Birth</td>
<td>
<select name='year'>
<option value='2015'>2015</option>
<option value='2016'>2016</option>
</select>
<select name='month'>
<option value='01'>January</option>
<option value='02'>February</option>
<option value='03'>March</option>
<option value='04'>April</option>
<option value='05'>May</option>
</select>                   
<select name='day'>
<option value='01'>1</option>
<option value='02'>2</option>
<option value='03'>3</option>
<option value='04'>4</option>
<option value='05'>5</option>            
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Designation</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength='100' name="designation" id="designation" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Department</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength='100' name="department" id="department" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image</td>
<td><input type="file" maxlength='100' name="image" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Register Yourself">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php                   
//create a connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'attendance');

//on the click of submit button 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    //capture the $_POST values  
    $name   = $_POST['empname'];
    $name   = trim($name);
    $email  = $_POST['emailid'];
    $email  = trim($email);
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $userid = trim($userid);
    $pwd    = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwd    = trim($pwd);
    $desg   = $_POST['designation'];
    $desg   = trim($desg);
    $dept   = $_POST['department'];
    $dept   = trim($dept);
    $day    = $_POST['day'];
    $month  = $_POST['month'];
    $year   = $_POST['year'];
    $date   = $year.$month.$day;

    //display a message if there is a blank entry for email
    if ($email=="") {
        echo "Please enter a valid email id";
    }

    //display a message if there is a blank entry for userid
    if ($userid=="") {
        echo "Please enter a valid User Id";
    }

    //check if the email id exists
    $sql_check_email = "select * from employee where emp_email='$email';";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_check_email);

    $aff_email = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

    // if email id exists ..display message 
    if ($aff_email==1) {

        $msgemail = "The email id exists";
        echo $msgemail;

    //display error message if there is an error 
    } else if ($aff_email>1) { 

        $msgemail = "There are multiple employees with the same email";
        echo $msgemail;

    //display message if there is an error firing the query
    } else if ($aff_email<0) {

        echo "There is an error ..Try again";

    }   

    //check if the user id exists 
    $sql_check_userid = "select * from employee_login where emp_uid='$userid';";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_check_userid);

    $aff_userid = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

    if ($aff_userid==1) {

        $umsg = "User id already exist";

        echo $umsg;

    //display error message if there is an error when the query is fired
    } else if ($aff_userid<0) {

        echo "There is an error ..Try again";

    }   

    //if neither the user id nor the email id exist, upload image and do the insert 
    if ($aff_userid==0 && $aff_email==0) {

        $target_path = "images/";
        $target_file = $target_path . basename ($_FILES['image']['name']);

        //if the image is moved to the images folder , do the insert
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {

            $image   = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

            $sql_ins = "INSERT INTO temporary_employee(emp_uid,emp_pwd,
                        emp_name,emp_email,emp_dob,emp_designation,
                        emp_department,emp_image) 
                        VALUES('$userid','$pwd','$name','$email','$date',
                        '$desg','$dept','$image')";

            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_ins);

            $aff_insert = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

            //display success message if insert is successfull
            if ($aff_insert==1) {

                echo "You have successfully registered ...awaiting approval by admin";

            //display message if there were no insert 
            } else if ($aff_insert==0) {

                echo "The registration has failed ..Try again";

            //diplay error message if there was an error while firing the insert query  
            } else if ($aff_insert<0) {

                echo "There was an error ..Try again";
            }   

        }


    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While using Image Uploading in the form you have to use the enctype in the form attribute.

```
<form action ="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have to encrypt the images and then only you have to post the image using HTML form...

Comment: @Naresh..thks ..it works fine ..
I also have a question here : when i changed my code to :
<form action ="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> , it was still giving me the same error . It was only after i changed my code to <form action ="test-reg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> , that the insertion was successfull . Without the image upload part , form action ="" , works perfectly fine . 
Can you tell me why this is so ?

Comment: Have you written the form uploader code in `test-reg.php` page right.

Comment: yes Naresh..thats right . my form and form uploader code is in the same file ..test-reg.php . But , my question remains ; when i work without a file upload control , and my form upload code is in the same file, form action="" works perfectly fine . But when i use a file upload control and my form upload code is in the same file, form action="" gives an error . Can you tell me why it is so ?

Comment: What Error are you getting @SabyasachiGupta. when you are using file control in the form with action="".

Comment: If you are using file uploder you have to specify the file in which the code is written since the file uploder will search for the `$_FILES` syntax and hence without specifying the path the data are not received to this function. If you use without the file control all the other data will be inserted correclty

Comment: i am getting the same error posted in my question "undefined index image" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122157/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-sabyasachi-gupta).

Comment: thks ..Naresh for all your clarifications

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<form action ="" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And try again.

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

Comment: @Mayank..thks ..it works fine